# Как получить тип данных из Текста?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Вот мой код :

```
cityInRussian :: Text -> City
cityInRussian "Арагацотн" = Aragatsotn
cityInRussian "Арарат"     = Ararat
cityInRussian "Армавир"    = Armavir
cityInRussian "Дилижан"    = Dilijan
cityInRussian "Гехаркуник" = Gegharkunik
cityInRussian "Гюмри"      = Gyumri
cityInRussian "Котайк"     = Kotayk
cityInRussian "Ширак"      = Shirak
cityInRussian "Сюник"      = Syunik
cityInRussian "Ванадзор"   = Vanadzor
cityInRussian "Ереван"     = Yerevan
```

И я получаю вот такую ошибку

```
 Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for ‘cityInRussian’:
       Patterns not matched:
           p   where p is not one of {"Ереван", "Ванадзор", Сюник", "Ширак","Котайк", "Гюмри", "Гехаркуник", "Дилижан", "Армавир", "Арарат", "Арагацотн"}
  |
36 | cityInRussian "Арагацотн" = Aragatsotn
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Как мне это исправить? Может тип функции должен быть таким:

```
textToCity :: Language -> Text -> Maybe City
```

Где тип City:

```
data City
   = Aragatsotn
   | Ararat
   | Armavir
   | Dilijan
   | Gegharkunik
   | Gyumri
   | Kotayk
   | Shirak
   | Syunik
   | Vanadzor
   | Yerevan
   deriving (Read, Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Comment: Задайте себе такой вопрос: чему равно `cityInRussian "Foo"`?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что непонятно что делать если в качестве параметра передать город не из списка.

Решить можно изменив тип функции на

```
cityInRussian :: Text -> Maybe City
cityInRussian "Арагацотн" = Just Aragatsotn
cityInRussian "Арарат"     = Just Ararat
cityInRussian "Армавир"    = Just Armavir
cityInRussian "Дилижан"    = Just Dilijan
cityInRussian "Гехаркуник" = Just Gegharkunik
cityInRussian "Гюмри"      = Just Gyumri
cityInRussian "Котайк"     = Just Kotayk
cityInRussian "Ширак"      = Just Shirak
cityInRussian "Сюник"      = Just Syunik
cityInRussian "Ванадзор"   = Just Vanadzor
cityInRussian "Ереван"     = Just Yerevan
cityInRussian _            = Nothing
```